# Using $Rev:$ SVN keyword in C# code?

Tags: c#, svn, syntax, tortoisesvn, revision

Does anyone know what the syntax is to use the file revision keyword within the code in C#? I know how to use it in SQL Server but I can't seem to get the syntax right. I have already added the property to the file in which I would like to display the version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your C# files should contain `$LastChangedRevision: $` to get the SVN revision added. However, you also need to set the `svn:keywords` property correctly for the files in which you want that value to be expanded.

For example, the following will result in a string containing the revision.

```
string revision = "$LastChangedRevision: $";
```

The `svn:keywords` property should include the `LastChangedRevision` in its space-separated list of values.

You can make this automatic for the `cs` extension by editing the TortoiseSVN configuration. To do this, go to the TortoiseSVN explorer menu and select `Settings...`. Then on the `General` tab, click the `Edit` button next to `Subversion configuration file:`.

Scroll down and add a line like this one into the `[auto-props]` section (just an example, you may have more or less keywords and you may also set other properties):

```
*.cs = svn:keywords=LastChangedDate LastChangedBy LastChangedRevision Id URL;
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! However, what I am actually having trouble with is accessing the property in my code. What is the syntax to, say, output that $Revision: $ as a string?

Comment: @badpanda: string revision = "$LastChangedRevision: $"; Check in the file and out again, and a revision will be filled in.

Comment: When its auto-propse called ? If I changed [auto-props] section, what should I to get changed data?

Comment: @Martin: I believe the auto-props are only applied to files when first added. If a file already exists in the repository, you'll have to manually add the props to each file.

Comment: And how can I get only number from LastChangedRevision? Because I need to add it into AssemblyInfo.cs - [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

Comment: There are several ways, such as embedding the keyword in a string and parsing it, or using SubWCRev. I recommend the latter. See [the answer from pete_s below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345803/using-rev-svn-keyword-in-c-sharp-code/5658770#5658770).

Comment: I would add a **recursive** `svn:keywords` SVN property on my SVN parent folder instead of adding the `*.cs` line to the SVN configuration file : so all developpers could have that property on any new files... OK the cons are that it would be the case for **every** files and not just `*.cs` ones, so that's perhaps not always a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can call SubWCRev.exe and get it to write the version number into your Resources.resx in your pre-build, and then clean up afterwards so that you don't need to mess around with other scripts, and svn does not repeatedly see Resources.resx as having changed.

1. Add string resources to your Resources.resx file, using the place-holders that SubWCRev.exe recognizes, for example:

   BuildTime = $WCNOW$

   CurrentSVNRevision = $WCREV$

   HasLocalModifications = $WCMODS?(local modifications detected): $
2. Add the following prebuild (to back-up your Resources.resx and have SubWCRev.exe replace the place-holders with the required values):

   copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)\Properties\Resources.resx" "$(ProjectDir)\Properties\Resources.resx.save"

   call "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe" "$(SolutionDir)\" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\Resources.resx" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\Resources.resx"
3. Add the following post-build to restore your Resources.resx:

   move /Y "$(ProjectDir)\Properties\Resources.resx.save" "$(ProjectDir)\Properties\Resources.resx"
4. Set the post-build event to run always (even if the build fails)
5. Use Resources.CurrentSVNRevision etc wherever you need it in your code.

I looked at lots of solutions, and then found this to be much simpler and more robust that anything else I found.  Hope it helps someone else.